# Is there any functional automation tool for testing native iPhone applications?

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, build-automation

I have been involved in doing web automation and Android automation testing. Currently we are looking for any iPhone functional testing tool which will help us to reduce the number of hours for regression testing. We are looking for an open source tool like Selenium or Robotium, where test cases are easier to write and implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wait until iOS 5 is released, I am sure you will find a component in Instruments that will do just what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Non open source option could be SeeTest from [experitest](http://experitest.com). It support both Android and iOS.

Comment: Hi, I heared about that tool.. Can you please tell me some positive or negative points about that tool after using it

Answer (score -1):

These days there are a number of projects to automate testing for native applications, including iphones. These two are the ones i see first on github searches.

https://github.com/TestingWithFrank/Frank

https://github.com/ios-driver/ios-driver

I remember there must be more but i do not recall their names